# Why does semimetals (particularly nearly compensated ones) have very strong magnetoresistance?

Tags: condensed-matter, magnetic-fields

It's well established that semimetals, i.e. metals with both electrons and holes, have a strongest enhancement of its resistance when subject to a magnetic field (namely magnetoresistance). From  the two-carrier model of electrical conductivity one can readily arrive at this conclusion, but I wonder what is the physically intuitive explanation for this behaviour?

Comment: Intuition is a highly personal thing. If the two carrier model is good, why is it not intuitive to you?

Comment: Because just knowing how to do the math doesn't help me understand what physical processes (in the real world) happen to get me there. I always tend to think about the real world picture behind mathematics. That's my kind of intuition.

Comment: But doing the math isn’t the key thing - it is the equations and how they are set up that matter.